# Swift Customized UIButton unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: swift, uibutton, selector, addtarget

As the title says, I got this error message:

```
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[{Project}.{UIView} tapAction:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x156406c70'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

When I was trying to customize a `UIButton` like this:

```
class BaseButton: UIButton {
    
    private var action: ((UIButton)->())?

    public func tapInside(target: Any?, action: ((UIButton)->())?) {
        self.action = action
        self.addTarget(target, action: #selector(tapAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc private func tapAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if let _f = action {
            _f(self)
        }
    }
    
}
```

I understand that I was trying something advanced without understanding the basics.

Please let me know if there is any other solution that I don't have to create a `tapAction` every time.

**Update**:
Details added to error message.

Comment: Full error message? But `target` isn't `self` in `addTarget()`, since later you redirect with your `action` closure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd share the FULL error message, you should have:

```
-[TheClass tapAction:] unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Where `TheClass` should be the class of the instance that called `tapInside(target:action:)`.

That's what might give you a tip on your issue.

Ie, `TheClass` is calling on itself the method `tapAction(_:)`, which is doesn't' know.
It's like writing `theClass.tapAction(someSender)`, this shouldn't compile, right?

The issue, is that in `addTarget(_:action:for:)`, the `target` is the one that implement the `action` (selector). In this case, it's `self`, the `BaseButton` instance.

So:

```
self.addTarget(target, action: #selector(tapAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

=>

```
self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tapAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Now, since you don't need anymore the `target` parameter, you can remove it from the method:

```
public func tapInside(target: Any?, action: ((UIButton)->())?) {...}
```

=>

```
public func tapInside(action: ((UIButton)->())?) {...}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually, I didn't recognize that `selector` should be inside the `target`.